# how to store and use data coming from service to components local array variable

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to fetch data from service

```
   this.admin.cartgrid().subscribe(data => this.add =data);
```

and store and then want sum of the total cost
       ngOnInit() {

```
    for(let i = 0; i<this.add.length; i++){
      this.sum = this.sum + this.add[i].Final_amt;    
    }
 }
```

but cant get the sum  . i think the data are not store in local array add.

here is my ts file

```
 export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

    add : cart[];
   sum : number=0

  constructor(private admin:AdminService,) {
   }
 ngOnInit() {
    this.admin.cartgrid().subscribe(data => this.add =data);
    this.buyer= sessionStorage.getItem('key-name');

    for(let i = 0; i<this.add.length; i++){
      this.sum = this.sum + this.add[i].Final_amt;    
    }
 }
```

here is my cart object

```
    export class cart {
    constructor(
       public Cartid:number,
       public Price_month : number,
       public total_month : number, 
       public total_price : number, 
       public buyer : string, 
       public seller : string, 
       public GST_amt : number, 
       public admin_profit : number, 
       public seller_adveriser_amt : number, 
       public Buy_Datetime : Date, 
       public Category : string, 
       public Subcategory : string, 
       public Final_amt : number, 
       public PRDName : string,
       public BYSESSION:string) {

    }
}
```

Comment: paste the content of this.add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your addition logic inside the subscribe logic. As you are subscribing to a observable which is an asynchronous operation.

After this code you can print `this.sum` and you will get the result.

```js
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

  add: cart[];
  sum: number = 0

  constructor(private admin: AdminService, ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('step 1')
    this.admin.cartgrid().subscribe(data => {
    console.log('step 2')
      this.add = data;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.add.length; i++) {
        this.sum = this.sum + this.add[i].Final_amt;
      }
    });
    console.log('step 3')
    this.buyer = sessionStorage.getItem('key-name');
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Observables - is wrapper around data stream and in your case `this.cartgrid()` is an observable which is asynchronous. So, JavaScript put asynchronous task in message queue when they return successful response and does not execute it right after it.

So in your case when you were writing the for loop outside the subscribe block, it was executing before the data is returned from the service. This was the reason your sum was zero.

If you want to debug you can add consoles in your code and check the sequence how they print. I have added in your code and output will be - step1, step3 and step2.

If you want to know more about Asynchronous in JavaScript- i would suggest you this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: can you plzz explain me what it mean by" As you are subscribing to a observable which is an asynchronous operation."?

Comment: I am updating your ask in answer.